# Instagram returning JSON in browser but not in PHP

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm using https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 to retrieve a user id. The url returns the proper JSON whenever I use it in a browser, however when I goto the url it in PHP with "get file contents" or "curl" it returns a full HTML page. The URL works without being logged in as well in the browser so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```php
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1";

$response = file_get_contents($url);
```

#### Using [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```php
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1";

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

In both cases `$response` contains valid JSON string.

Comment: Isn't this the two ways the OP said they tried, but the result was a full HTML page instead of the JSON? Granted the OP didn't supply ANY CODE of what they tried, or any debugging info....

Comment: Yes in both cases it return a strange html page - https://glambassador.co/instatest.php